# Select total count of elements group by

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, group-by

I have an Animal Zoo.

**Zoo Table**

```
id | name |
```

**Animal Table**

```
id | zoo_id | name |    type
1     1       Horse      0
2     1       Elephant   0   
3     1       Parrot     1
4     2       Whale      2     
5     2       Fox        0
6     1       Snake      3
```

I want to select all the *zoo data* along with the *total number of animals of that zoo* and *all the animal type existing in that zoo*

**MySQL**

```
SELECT zoo.id as zooid,zoo.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM animal WHERE animal.zoo_id = zoo.id) as total_animals
 FROM zoo;
```

But how am i able to get *all the animal type existing in that zoo*

**Expected Result**

```
zooid | name |  total | available_types
 1      USAZOO   4        0 1 3    
 2      UKZOO    2        0 2
```

And since i am going to select a lot of Zoo therefore **performance matters**

Comment: Do a JOIN. With a GROUP BY.

Comment: Elaborate please @jarlh

Comment: Step 1) JOIN zoo with animal. Step 2) Do a GROUP BY.

Comment: You comments make me laugh:) but I think he needs group_concat so thats not what he is looking for @jarlh

Comment: The group_concat is included in Step 2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT :

```
SELECT zoo.id as zooid,zoo.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM animal WHERE animal.zoo_id = zoo.id) as total_animals,
       group_concat(type separator ' ')
FROM zoo
GROUP BY zoo.id,zoo.name
```

I think you need this to the zoo names as well, how did you get your name results? Anyway -

```
SELECT zoo.id as zooid,
       group_concat(zoo.name separator ' ') as zoo_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM animal WHERE animal.zoo_id = zoo.id) as total_animals,
       group_concat(type separator ' ')
FROM zoo
GROUP BY zoo.id
```

And you should do it with a join:

```
SELECT zoo.id as zooid,
       group_concat(zoo.name separator ' ') as zoo_name,
       COUNT(*) as total_animals,
       group_concat(type separator ' ')
FROM zoo
INNER JOIN animals
 ON animal.zoo_id = zoo.id
GROUP BY zoo.id
```

Comment: Can't you just replace the sub-query with count(*)?

Comment: @jarlh you mean add join and then count all, yes I've add this solution as well now.

Comment: So which one is the best ? last one ?

Comment: @JohnDoe I believe so, but there are people that would prefer the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Refining the answer of sagi:

```
SELECT Zoo.id as zooid, zoo.name AS name,
       COUNT(*) AS total,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type separator ' ') AS available_types
FROM Zoo
INNER JOIN Animal
 ON Animal.zoo_id = zoo.id
GROUP BY zoo.id
```

This gives you only the distinct types of animals. You can play around with it here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b21b/11)